# How to use loop variables in javascript outside of the loop?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to be able to use a variable from within a loop, outside of the loop to be used in javascript between script tags.  Preferably not with script tags and in a file but script tags to start...

I have this that doesn't work:

```
<% @line_items.each do |li| %>
<button type="button" onclick="mockupColor<%= "#{li.id}" %>()"></button>
<div id="tshirt-div-<%= "#{li.id}" %>">
#code
<script>
    function mockupColor<%= li.id %>(){
        document.getElementById("tshirt-div-<%= "#{li.id}" %>").style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    }, false);
</script>
<% end %>
```

**Error**: mockupColor1 is not defined

This does work:

```
<% @line_items.each do |li| %>
<button type="button" onclick="mockupColor"></button>
<div id="tshirt-div">
#code
<% end %>
<script>
    function mockupColor(){
        document.getElementById("tshirt-div").style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    }, false);
</script>
```

The issue is I need to be able to call for the li.id because once i figure this function issue out, the colors will change depending on the li.id.

Is there a way to somehow match up the `li.id` from the loop in a script tag outside of the loop?

I don't see why this won't work because I have definitely used javascript within loops before and worked out fine.  I used similar code in a fields_for loop in an app and using functions this way worked out perfectly fine...For whatever reason, not this time.  Or is there something I am missing and not doing right?

HTML:
(inside loop)

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-color="796" data-target="#exampleModal2-796" id="#exampleModal2-796"  onclick="mockupColor()">

<script>
function mockupColor() {
   document.getElementById("tshirt-div-796").style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
};
</script>
```

Comment: What's the generated html/javascript code?

Comment: Added the html code for what isn't working.  Even removing the ID from the loop, it will not work inside the loop

Comment: I suggest checking out the [Working with JavaScript in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#unobtrusive-javascript) guide which uses a similar example.

Answer (score 1):

While you could fix it by adding the proper parentheses and delimiters around the call to `mockColor` -- instead, rather than using inline handlers (which are widely considered to be pretty poor practice), consider adding a data attribute instead, and then using event delegation to watch for clicks of a `button` inside the container:

```
<button type="button" data-color="<%= "{li.id}" %>"></button>
<div>
```

and

```
container.addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  if (!target.matches('button')) {
    return;
  }
  target.nextElementSibling.style.backgroundColor = '#' + target.dataset.color;
});
```

where `container` is the container around the buttons and divs.

Note that with the use of `nextElementSibling`, there's no need to give the `<div>`s `id`s anymore. (numeric-indexed IDs are best avoided anyway)

Comment: And this goes inside the  loop or outside?

Comment: The HTML part needs to be part of the loop for the `li.id` to be defined, of course - the Javascript should be outside (like in a single standalone `<script>` tag, which runs *once*)

Answer (score 0):

```
<% @line_items.each do |li| %>
   <button type="button" onclick="mockupColor(<%= "#{li.id}" %>)"></button>
   <div id="tshirt-div-<%= "#{li.id}" %>">#code</div>   
<% end %>
<script>
    function mockupColor(id){
        document.getElementById("tshirt-div-"+id).style.backgroundColor = '#000000';
    );
</script>
```

You do not need to loop java script function. The function should just accept the JavaScript variable and process as the java script.